# Self-irony, self irony

Tags: expressions

Self-irony is very popular in my home country, Denmark, and I find it defined on the Internet as "the ability to laugh at oneself, to take oneself lightly".

I also find it in some dictionaries but apparently not in the most widely used. Does the word (combo) exist or don't native English speakers know how to laugh at themselves?

Comment: In what context do you use "self-irony" in Denmark? Can you list an example or two?

Comment: Here are three examples off the top of my head: "I've always been very proud of my wrinkles. I worked very hard to get them." Or "I have a great future behind me." Or a woman in a baking competition who by mistake put salt in her cake instead of sugar: "I'm very good at following recipes."

Comment: Please edit your question by clicking on **edit**.

Comment: @Rathony You can used `[edit]` to produce a link to the [edit] page for the question/answer on which you're commenting.

Comment: I don't think you'll find quite the level of dry wit you are used to in other parts of the world.

Answer (score 4):

Are you looking for "self-deprecating"?

> Jim is self-deprecating; he's always the first to laugh at himself when he makes a silly mistake.

[Self-deprecating](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/self-deprecating)

> meant to make oneself or the things one does seem unimportant: "self-deprecating humor"

Comment: This is a good idea but to my ear it is incomplete.  I think it should be *self-deprecating humor.*